# combobox add items throw Exception "Specific cast is not valid"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

Hi i have the following code
to add some items into combobox **When** i do the code it in a thread i have the following exception "Specific cast is not valid" **But** when do it in main form thread there is no exception.
any idea how to solve this?

```
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

        //Auto Complete
        comboBox3.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        comboBox3.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;

        //no specific formatting
        comboBox3.FormattingEnabled = true;

        Thread th1 = new Thread(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    //# Code Start

                    //Some Text 
                    String[] TicketStatus = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

                    //Throw Exception "Specific cast is not valid"
                    comboBox3.Items.AddRange(TicketStatus);

                    //# Code End
                }
                catch (Exception c) { MessageBox.Show(c.Message); }
            });
        th1.Start();
```

like this no Exception

```
  Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

        //Auto Complete
        comboBox3.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        comboBox3.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;

        //no specific formatting
        comboBox3.FormattingEnabled = true;


        //# Code Start

        //Some Text 
        String[] TicketStatus = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

        //Throw Exception "Specific cast is not valid"
        comboBox3.Items.AddRange(TicketStatus);

        //# Code End
```

Comment: You should not update gui controls on a thread. Search for `control.Invoke()` to update controls from a non-gui thread.

Comment: Even though I don't like this `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls`, I have to say that your code worked without any problems here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access UI elements from a thread other than the UI thread.

You'll have to marshall the setter code back to the UI thread.

Use `InvokeRequired` to do so.

Comment: i can do that with the following code : Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

Comment: Never understood bad-code practice properties like `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls`. You should forget that it exists...

Comment: @Joeren these things are sometimes needed in unit tests.. but generally I agree

Comment: @DrKoch yes you can try it.

Comment: Let it be known that `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` is documented that it should only be used for ease of debugging. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls.aspx):  _Set CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to true to find and diagnose this thread activity more easily while debugging._ In a non-debug environment it looks like the property itself may be completely ignored.